# ¿Como se usa CamelCase en Swift3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

¿Como puedo usar CamelCase en un String que uso en Swift 3? El problema es que nu cuento con un ejemplo de como podria aplicarlo.

Por ejemplo uso una variable como la siguiente:

> var textoPrueba: String ="amelCase es un estilo de escritura que se
>   aplica a frases o palabras compuestas. El nombre se debe a que las
>   mayúsculas a lo largo de una palabra en CamelCase se asemejan a las
>   jorobas de un camello."

Como puedo usar CamelCase en ese String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, tienes dudas de como aplicar CamelCase a ese string. La cuestión es que CamelCase es un conjunto de reglas que se aplican para los identificadores que denotan variables, tipos, funciones y otras entidades de tu código fuente y tu documentación. Fijate que en ese string que has declarado no tienes palabras compuestas, mayormente porque es una cadena de caracteres que no identifican nada. Ironicamente, estás usando CamelCase en tu variable **textoPrueba**.

Comment: Si tienes razon, no habia entendido sobre CamelCase, pero ya se como funciona.